# how to put a node below another in a chain

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-chains

I have the following chain:

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right,>=latex,node distance=0pt]
     \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] (rr) {$I$};
     \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,draw=white,minimum width=0.8cm]{};
     % the rectangular shape with vertical lines
     \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
     draw, rectangle split horizontal,text height=0.5cm,text depth=0.5cm,on chain,inner ysep=0pt] (wa) {};
     \fill[white] ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth,yshift=-\pgflinewidth]wa.north west) 
       rectangle ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=\pgflinewidth]wa.south);
     % the circle
     \node[draw,circle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] (se) {$U_1$};
     \node[draw,diamond,on chain,minimum size=0.2cm,xshift=0.7cm] (see) {};
     { [start branch=numbers going below] } % just a declaration,
     \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,draw=white,minimum width=0.7cm]{};
     % rect2
     \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
     draw, rectangle split horizontal,text height=0.5cm,text depth=0.5cm,on chain,inner ysep=0pt] (wa2) {};
     \fill[white] ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth,yshift=-\pgflinewidth]wa2.north west) 
       rectangle ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=\pgflinewidth]wa2.south);
     % the circle 2
     \node[draw,circle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] (se2) {$U_2$};
     % the arrows and labels
     \draw[->] (se.east) -- +(20pt,0) node[midway,above] {$\mu_1$};
     \draw[->] (see.east) -- +(20pt,0) node[midway,above] {$\mu_1$};
     \draw[->] (se2.east) -- +(20pt,0) node[midway,above] {$\mu_2$};
     \draw[<-] (wa.west) -- +(-20pt,0) node[midway,above] {$\lambda$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

Which is a connection between two queues as shown in the picture:

However I would like to add another node below the diamond with an arrow. How to do this? I searched some solutions but they do not really fit my code...

[image]

Comment: Please post **complete** code. That is much more useful than fragments. I guess you need the `chains` library for this, but I still get errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to load the `scopes` library for tikz, so in your preamble (that you should have posted as well above), you should add

```
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
```

Then, edit the start of your chain as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,node distance=0pt]
  { [start chain=going right]
```

Finally, put the branch at the end of your chain (and edit the labels accordingly):

```
  % the branch
    {[continue branch=numbers]
      \node[draw,circle,on chain,minimum size=1cm,yshift=-0.7cm] (se3) {$U_3$};
      \draw[->] (see.south) -- +(0,-20pt) node[midway,left] {$\mu_3$};
    }
  } % closing brace from above
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Maybe you should stick to the same unit throughout the whole chain, so eiter use `pt` or `cm`, since there might be rounding errors otherwise. Don’t you think?

Answer (score 2):

Note that you could do without `scopes` if you wished by just using a second chain and `chainin`. However, for some reason, it is very fiddly to get the positioning right. I'm assuming this is because of the many shifts etc. in the code though I'm by no means sure.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes}% both are needed for the original code in the question

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,>=latex,node distance=0pt]
  { [start chain=trunk going right]
     \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] (rr) {$I$};
     \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,draw=white,minimum width=0.8cm]{};
     % the rectangular shape with vertical lines
     \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
     draw, rectangle split horizontal,text height=0.5cm,text depth=0.5cm,on chain,inner ysep=0pt] (wa) {};
     \fill[white] ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth,yshift=-\pgflinewidth]wa.north west)
       rectangle ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=\pgflinewidth]wa.south);
     % the circle
     \node[draw,circle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] (se) {$U_1$};
     \node[draw,diamond,on chain,minimum size=0.2cm,xshift=7mm] (see) {};
     \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,draw=white,minimum width=0.7cm]{};
     % rect2
     \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
     draw, rectangle split horizontal,text height=0.5cm,text depth=0.5cm,on chain,inner ysep=0pt] (wa2) {};
     \fill[white] ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth,yshift=-\pgflinewidth]wa2.north west)
       rectangle ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=\pgflinewidth]wa2.south);
     % the circle 2
     \node[draw,circle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] (se2) {$U_2$};
  }
  % the branch
  { [start chain=numbers going below]
       \chainin (see);
       \node[draw,diamond,on chain,minimum size=.2cm,yshift=-1cm,xshift=-4.75mm] (branchnode) {};
  }
 % the arrows and labels
 \draw[->] (se.east) -- +(7mm,0) node[midway,above] {$\mu_1$};
 \draw[->] (see.east) -- +(7mm,0) node[midway,above] {$\mu_1$};
 \draw[->] (se2.east) -- +(7mm,0) node[midway,above] {$\mu_2$};
 \draw[<-] (wa.west) -- +(-7mm,0) node[midway,above] {$\lambda$};
 \draw[->] (see.south) -- (branchnode);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: second chain with chainin]